# jScrollPane Wordpress plugin - no idea how to use it

Tags: wordpress, plugins, jscrollpane

I have no experience with Java or JavaScript. I have tried to make custom scroll bars for months with various methods, including CSS. I never managed to achieve a single thing.

There appears to be exactly one custom scroll bar plugin for Wordpress, which is [jScrollPane](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-jscrollpane/). So I think I should spend some time trying to get it to work. But I don't understand anything.

What is a "Selector"? Specifying a selector is mandatory.

Does the plugin let me to customize the graphical appearance of the scroll bars in other ways than simply changing their color or size? I thought it did, but the settings page does not seem to include any way of doing so. I would have liked to create the scroll bar of my own image files.

Please, just help me. I've been banging my head on this for months and never managed to change the color of one pixel. I need a tutorial that doesn't assume I know anything besides using FTP and writing simple Wordpress themes in CSS, HTML and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.  Maybe you can do what you need - this "custom scroll bar" - without using the jScrollPane Wordpress plugin you cited.  Q: What is the "end goal"?
2. If you wish to use this particular plugin, you'll need the following:

   a) a web server with Wordpress installed

   b) the jScrollPane plugin

   c) Some knowledge of HTML, CSS, Javascript and WordPress
3. This has nothing do with "Java".  JavaScript is not Java - they're completely different things.  Even though Java also happens to have a "jScrollPane", it has nothing to do with your "jScrollPane" plugin.  They're completely separate.
4. Your jScrollPane is documented here:

   http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/
5. If you're not familiar with how to install a ready-made plugin (like your jScrollPane), here's a good reference:

   http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/step-by-step-guide-to-install-a-wordpress-plugin-for-beginners/

   Manual installation for your jScrollPane plugin is also documented [here](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)
6. Finally, here's a good tutorial to get started with Javascript (the language) and jQuery (a Javascript framework):

   http://www.w3schools.com/js/

   http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/

'Hope that helps